# Composite Unique Index created on each deploy

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm using Spring 3.2 with Hibernate 4.2.1.Final and MySql 5.5.

Each time I reload my webapp hibernate creates a new Composite Unique Index of my entities.

For example in my entity I have:

@Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "field1", "field2" }) })

On each deploy I have a new unique index on those two field.

Is this a bug?

Thank you
Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give name of composite unique index key

eg:

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(name="field1_field2_unique_key", columnNames = { "field1", "field2" }) })
```

here composite unique index key name is : field1_field2_unique_key

Comment: I had not thought of this option. I think it can work as a workaround. Thank you!!